# Query to return all transactions of an asset as a JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, join, for-json

I have the two tables `assets` and `transactions` in my database, whereby transactions are connected to assets by the columns `transactions.from_id` and `transactions.to_id`:

assets:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 |
| 2 | a2 |
| 3 | a3 |

transactions:

| id | title | from_id | to_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | t1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | t2 | 2 | 3 |

I would like to query the assets table and add a column `transactions` to the result, where all transactions related to an asset are listed in a json array like so:

desired query result:

| id | title | transactions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | [{"id": 1, "title": "t1"}] |
| 2 | a2 | [{"id": 1, "title": "t1"}, {"id": 2, "title": "t2"}] |
| 3 | a3 | [{"id": 2, "title": "t2"}] |

I have difficulties to get all connected transactions into one array since the transactions can either be connected to an asset by the column from_id or to_id. My current status is this:

query:

```
WITH mod_assets AS (
  SELECT
  a.id,
  a.title,
  json_array(
    json_object(
     'id', t_ex.id,
     'title', t_ex.title
    )
  ) expenses,
  json_array(
    json_object(
      'id', t_in.id,
      'title', t_in.title
    )
  ) incomes
  FROM assets AS a
  LEFT JOIN transactions AS t_ex ON a.id = t_ex.from_id
  LEFT JOIN transactions AS t_in ON a.id = t_in.to_id
)
SELECT * FROM mod_assets;
```

result:

| id | title | expenses | incomes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | [{"id": 1, "title": "t1"}] | [{"id": null, "title": null}] |
| 2 | a2 | [{"id": 2, "title": "t2"}] | [{"id": 1, "title": "t1"}] |
| 3 | a3 | [{"id": null, "title": null}] | [{"id": 2, "title": "t2"}] |

But this is not what I want. I also tried a bunch of other queries and maybe the closest I got was this one, but the `GROUP BY` statement does not combine the json array on transactions but returns only the first transaction:

query:

```
WITH mod_assets AS (
  SELECT
  a.id,
  a.title,
  t.id AS t_id,
  t.title AS t_title
  FROM assets AS a
  INNER JOIN transactions AS t
  ON a.id = t.from_id
  UNION
  SELECT a.id, a.title, t.id, t.title
  FROM assets AS a
  INNER JOIN transactions AS t
  ON a.id = t.to_id
)
SELECT
mod_assets.id,
mod_assets.title,
json_array(
  json_object(
    'id', mod_assets.t_id,
    'title', mod_assets.t_title
  )
) transactions
FROM mod_assets
GROUP BY mod_assets.id
```

result:

| id | title | transactions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | [{"id": 1, "title": "t1"}] |
| 2 | a2 | [{"id": 1, "title": "t1"}] |
| 3 | a3 | [{"id": 2, "title": "t2"}] |

Can somebody explain what I need to do?

Comment: Why do you want this? It's slower and takes *more* space, CPU and bandwidth than returning the JOIN results, both on the server *and* client - you have to parse that JSON. ORMs like Entity Framework will convert related objects into collections automagically anyway.

Comment: In any case, query results are converted to JSON using `FOR JSON`, not `JSON_ARRAY`.

Comment: Syntax like `INNER JOIN \`transactions\` AS t` isn't valid T-SQL; it doesn't use backticks (`\``) for delimit identifying.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a MySQL query to SQL Server? MySQL lacks a *ton* of features that are available in SQL Server for almost 20 years. Many features like recursive CTEs, windowing functions were only added in MySQL 8.0 and still have rough edges. The workarounds needed in MySQL are *not* needed in SQL Server

Comment: In this case, *ORMs* like EF can fix up relations between objects, you don't have to do so in SQL. In SQL, you can use a recursive CTE to get all related entries OR you can use SQL Server's [Graph Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-architecture?view=sql-server-ver16) functionality to say you want a root's transactions, with a simpler query. If you had a simple hierarchy, an indexed `hierarchyid` would eliminate the need for recursive CTEs and improve performance

Comment: Well, I'm not very familiar with SQL SERVER so far and have only limited MySQL experience, hence tried what I could. I have no idea about the options mentioned in the comments but will look it up. Still, if somebody could provide a working query I would appreciate it :)

Comment: Just use a single join on transactions where assetid in (from_id, to_id). I would convert it to a correlated subquery json

Comment: @siggemannen, getting closer! Still does not return all transactions in one array but   one row for each connected transaction

Comment: Did u do the correlated subquery thing

Comment: @siggemannen My query now looks like `SELECT a.id, a.title, json_array(json_object( 'id', t.id, 'title', t.title )) 'transactions' FROM assets AS a LEFT JOIN transactions AS t ON a.id IN (t.from_id, t.to_id) GROUP BY a.id;` I'm not sure what is meant by a correlated subquery thing :/

Comment: SELECT a.id, a.title, (select t.id, t.title from transactions where  a.id IN (t.from_id, t.to_id) for json path) as transactions
FROM assets AS a;

Comment: I don't see why this is recursive, it seems you just want a single level of from and to nodes. And what are you actually using SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: that was an edit made by Panagiotis Kanavos. I did not mention recursive in the first place

Comment: @Charlieface you are correct, and i am using SQL Server

Comment: @siggemannen: for some reason using JSON PATH always throws a syntax error in php myadmin

Comment: isn't phpmyadmin used with mysql?

Comment: Works fine with my fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/rIK8RbOs but it actually uses SQL Server, and not MySQL which are different databases that has different syntax

Comment: Oh wow, that's embarrassing. I assumed that the database on the server is SQL Server. Apparently it's not, and I'm using MySQL...

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you were using SQL Server:**

It seems you don't actually want recursive results (which would have implied you want transactions connected to other transactions, recursively).

You can union together two joins onto `transactions`, in an `APPLY`, then use `FOR JSON PATH` to aggregate them into a single JSON.

```sql
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.title,
  t.transactions
FROM assets AS a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      t.id,
      t.title
    FROM transactions AS t
    WHERE a.id = t.from_id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      t.id,
      t.title
    FROM transactions AS t
    WHERE a.id = t.to_id

    FOR JSON PATH
) AS t(transactions);
```

---

MySQL syntax is a bit different, but essentially the same concept: do a lateral join, with the aggregation inside.

```sql
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.title,
  t.transactions
FROM assets AS a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      json_arrayagg(
        json_object(
          'id', mod_assets.t_id,
          'title', mod_assets.t_title
        )
      ) AS transactions
    FROM (
        SELECT
          t.id,
          t.title
        FROM transactions AS t
        WHERE a.id = t.from_id

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
          t.id,
          t.title
        FROM transactions AS t
        WHERE a.id = t.to_id
    ) AS t
) AS t;
```

Comment: thank you for your effort and the answer. As I just found out I am using MySQL not SQL Server, I can't use the query you posted. I will make that clear in the question right now.

Comment: That's what not you tagged ([[tag:sql-server]]) or [told us 9 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76702469/query-to-return-all-transactions-of-an-asset-as-a-json-array#comment135228501_76702469) @maxischl ... If you are using MySQL, as many of us suspected, you *need* to correct your post and clean up your incorrect comments.

Comment: I know, I'm sorry

Comment: I just found out in the comment section above... really embarrassing..

Comment: Then fix your post, as I mentioned, @maxischl . Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76702469/edit) feature and delete the comments where you tell us you're using SQL Server to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @Charlieface this throws an error still, I think there is an issues with the mod_assets declaration. i tried to change it to t, but it still throws an error

Comment: Please construct a https://dbfiddle.uk with the table definitions and some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that might work for mysql:

```sql
select *
, (select CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(json_object('id', id, 'title',title)), ']') from (
    select  1, 't1', 1, 2
    union all  select 2, 't2', 2, 3
) t (id,title,from_id,to_id)
  where assets.id IN (from_id, to_id)
  
) as transactions
from (
    select  1, 'a1'
    union all   select 2, 'a2'
    union all   select 3, 'a3'
) assets (id,title)
```

You can replace the unions with your tables. GROUP_CONCAT collects the values together and CONCAT creates the necessary array.

Btw, I had to dust off 20 years old mysql knowledge, next time try to set correct database provider in your tags

Edit different version without string functions:

```sql
select *
, (select JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', id, 'title',title)) from (
    select  1, 't1', 1, 2
    union all  select 2, 't2', 2, 3
) t (id,title,from_id,to_id)
  where assets.id IN (from_id, to_id) 
) as transactions
from (
    select  1, 'a1'
    union all   select 2, 'a2'
    union all   select 3, 'a3'
) assets (id,title)
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg you don't need `GROUP_CONCAT` on modern versions